# How to delete firebase anonymous UID after login with Credential?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My app makes the user create a new anonymous ID automatically when downloading the app and when the user logs in, for example, by Facebook, the app change UID.

The problem is when I call `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential`, It creates a new UID or change to UID that links to this credential, and the anonymous ID is never deleted. If many users relogin this app, many unuse anonymous ID and data will be garbage in firebase.

I have an idea to store UID in a variable, and when sign-in is successful, I delete using that UID, but firebase allows delete UID only current account. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to allow a user that you signed in anonymously to upgrade to an identified account. The idiomatic way to do that is to **link** the Facebook account to the existing anonymous account, so that the UID remains the same. To do this, follow the process described in the documentation on [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) and in the FlutterFire documentation on [linking user accounts](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#linking-user-accounts).

Comment: yes I want that, but if that facebook account already exist in firebase linkWithCredential is cannot use anymore

Comment: That's correct, which is why you shouldn't call `signInWith...` but `linkWith...`.